# How to mock a function of React Component and mount the component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

I have a react component that uses fetch API to get posts. Now while "jest testing" I want to mock fetch API method to return json data from a file. Mount the component for testing to count the number of posts by finding the class count. Below is the code.

Test file code

```
    import React from 'react';
    import { mount } from 'enzyme';
    import dummyjson from '../dummydata.json';
    import DemoApp from '../index';

    describe('xxxx test component', () => {
  it('first test', async () => {
    global.fetch = jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve(dummyjson));
    const wrapper = shallow(<DemoApp />, { disableLifecycleMethods: true });
    expect(wrapper.state('isLoaded')).toBe(false);
    await wrapper.instance().loadPosts();
    expect(wrapper.state('isLoaded')).toBe(true);
  });
    });
```

React component code

```
        import React from 'react';
    /* eslint class-methods-use-this: ['error', { 'exceptMethods': ['fetch'] }] */

    export default class DemoApp extends React.Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          error: null,
          isLoaded: false,
          items: [],
        };
      }

   componentDidMount() {
    this.loadPosts().then(
      (result) => {
        this.setState({
          isLoaded: true,
          items: result,
        });
      },
      (error) => {
        this.setState({
          isLoaded: true,
          error,
        });
      },
    );
  }

  loadPosts() {
    return fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
      .then(res => res.json()).then(result => result)
      .catch(error => error);
  }

      render() {
        const { error, isLoaded, items } = this.state;
        if (error) {
          return <div>Error: {error.message}</div>;
        } else if (!isLoaded) {
          return <div>Loading...</div>;
        }
        return (
          <div>
            {items.map(item => <div className="somecssclass"> {item.title} {item.title}</div>)}
          </div>
        );
      }
    }
```

Below is dummydata json

```
    [
    {
      "userId": 1,
      "id": 1,
      "title": "sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit",
      "body": "quia et suscipit\nsuscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et cum\nreprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totam\nnostrum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto"
    },
    {
      "userId": 1,
      "id": 2,
      "title": "qui est esse",
      "body": "est rerum tempore vitae\nsequi sint nihil reprehenderit dolor beatae ea dolores neque\nfugiat blanditiis voluptate porro vel nihil molestiae ut reiciendis\nqui aperiam non debitis possimus qui neque nisi nulla"
    }
]
```

I am getting below error below error/warning even though I provided below exception for fetch method in react component class file.
/* eslint class-methods-use-this: ['error', { 'exceptMethods': ['fetch'] }] */

[image]

How can we fix this warning/error?

Any help is highly appreciated. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is race condition. `loadPosts` is asynchronous, while test is synchronous, and there is no promise to chain to wait for `fetch` promise chain to be fulfilled.

There are problems with control flow and testing methodology. `loadPosts` needs to return a promise, so it could be chained:

```
  loadPosts() {
    return fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')...;
  }
```

A proper way to unit-test it is to test `loadPosts` in one test and test it directly:

```
  it('...', async () => {
    global.fetch = jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve(dummyjson));
    const wrapper = shallow(<DemoApp />, { disableLifecycleMethods: true });
    expect(wrapper.state('isLoaded').toBe(false);
    await wrapper.instance().loadPosts();
    expect(wrapper.state('isLoaded').toBe(true);
  });
```

And in another test `loadPosts` can be stubbed/mocked and asserted that it's called in `componentDidMount`.

Also notice that `global.fetch =` replaces it once and for all. It should preferably be mocked with `jest.stub`.

Comment: if return fetch is used then getting error - Expected 'this' to be used by class method 'loadPosts'. (class-methods-use-this). Any idea?

Comment: It's not an error but warning. Disable https://eslint.org/docs/rules/class-methods-use-this rule then. It may be useful to suggest methods to be refactored but here it's of no use.

Comment: Updated the info in question.

Comment: I suppose it should be `{ 'exceptMethods': ['loadPosts'] }`. `fetch` is not a method. And I'd suggest to disable it because such cases are often in React due to how classes are used there.

Comment: with this approach I can't get following thing to work:
`expect(global.fetch).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);`

Comment: @maracuja-juice If `fetch` is global and it's called, `expect(global.fetch).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)` assertion should pass. If it doesn't pass this means that some of those conditions aren't true. Consider asking the question that reflects your case with https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve , it likely differs from the OP.